# BeautifulSoup scraping: I'm confused

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape [this site](http://www.civicinfo.bc.ca/bids?pn=1), and I want to check all of the anchor tags.

I have imported beautifulsoup 4.3.2 and here is my code:

```
url = """http://www.civicinfo.bc.ca/bids?pn=1"""
Html = urlopen(url).read()
Soup = BeautifulSoup(Html, 'html.parser')
Content = Soup.find_all('a')
```

My problem is that Content is always empty (i.e. Content = []). Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) `html.parser` is not very lenient before certain versions of Python. So you're likely looking at some malformed HTML.

What you want to do works if you use `lxml` instead of `html.parser`

From [the documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#improving-performance):

> That said, there are things you can do to speed up Beautiful Soup. If
>   you’re not using lxml as the underlying parser, my advice is to start.
>   Beautiful Soup parses documents significantly faster using lxml than
>   using html.parser or html5lib.

So the relevant code would be:

```
Soup = BeautifulSoup(Html, 'lxml')
```